# data not being published: unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, mysql, html, forum

I'm having trouble with the way I'm doing it, I've tried some different ways but nothing seems to work.

When I have it like the code below, it works but it doesn't insert the username data.

I get the error page with message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING"

```
<?php

include "connect.php"; //connection string

print "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css' type='text/css'>";

print "<table class='maintables'>";

print "<tr class='headline'><td>Post a message</td></tr>";

print "<tr class='maintables'><td>";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{

   $name=$_POST['name'];

   $yourpost=$_POST['yourpost'];

   $subject=$_POST['subject'];

   if(strlen($name)<1)

   {

      print "You did not type in a name."; //no name entered

   }

   else if(strlen($yourpost)<1)

   {

      print "You did not type in a post."; //no post entered

   }

   else if(strlen($subject)<1)

   {

      print "You did not enter a subject."; //no subject entered

   }

   else

   {

      $thedate=date("U"); //get unix timestamp

      $displaytime=date("F j, Y, g:i a");

      //we now strip HTML injections

      $subject=strip_tags($subject);

      $name=strip_tags($name);

      $yourpost=strip_tags($yourpost); 

      $insertpost="INSERT INTO forumtutorial_posts(author,title,post,showtime,realtime,lastposter) values('$name','$subject','$yourpost','$displaytime','$thedate','$name')";

      mysql_query($insertpost) or die("Could not insert post"); //insert post

      print "Message posted, go back to <A href='index.php'>Forum</a>.";

   }



}

else

{

   print "<form action='post.php' method='post'>";

   print "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='<? echo("$_SESSION[usr_name]");?>' size='20'><br>";

   print "Subject:<br>";

   print "<input type='text' name='subject' size='20'><br>";

   print "Your message:<br>";

   print "<textarea name='yourpost' rows='5' cols='40'></textarea><br>";

   print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'></form>";



}

print "</td></tr></table>";

?>
```

If I make it so that users put the username as they desire, it works but I want it to work like the code above with our system session.

Is there another way around? thanks!

Comment: Is this the complete error message? No line number?

Comment: I tried this way too > <? echo('$_SESSION[usr_name]');?> but that didn't work either. When I use that code, I don't get an error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" but it just doesn't insert the data into mysql.

Comment: Hi Tadeck, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a3761627/public_html/forum/post.php on line 176

Comment: I tried this too: print '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<? echo("$_SESSION[usr_name]");?>" size="20"><br>';

Comment: Please post and clearly label line 176 of post.php

Comment: @NickkN: See my answer. Which line exactly is line 176? Your lines are not numbered, so it is hard to tell. Also code better looks in question or (less preferably) separate site (such as ideone.com, pastebin.com or codepad.com), not in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

You provided not many details, but I see at least one syntax error here:

```
print "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='<? echo("$_SESSION[usr_name]");?>' size='20'><br>";
```

You just lack valid characters between string and variable:

```
print "<input (...) echo("$_SESSION[usr_name]"); (...)";
                         ^^                 ^^
```

But trying to guess what you wanted, I bet you basically include PHP code within string, within PHP code, and you do it incorrectly.

### Solution

Do this like that instead:

```
print "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$_SESSION[usr_name]' size='20'><br>";
```

or even cleaner:

```
print '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="' . $_SESSION[usr_name] . '" size="20"><br>';
```

Comment: Thanks Tadeck that did the trick and I'm gonna clean the code up too. I'm only learning...

Comment: There is still a problem. It doesn't show html text only non html.. I'm guessing thats an error in post again? right?

Comment: @NickkN: Make sure this is server issue, not browser issue. You can check the exact HTML generated by the server by hitting _Ctrl_ + _U_ when your browser loads the page, then you will see generated HTML in separate window or tab. I bet this is browser issue.